# Driving Bi-Color LEDs, 1.25m cable

Tags: led, logic-gates

I need to drive bi-color LEDs, wired anti-parallel at the far end of a 1.25 m cable.

The LEDs take 15 mA.

To drive this I am planning on using a full-bridge (H-bridge) composed of two logic gate inverters and the LEDs in between. To achieve the current I need the "Ultra-high-speed" (low Rout) gates to be able to drive the 15 mA in steady state. My concern is that the inverters will launch fast edges and the cable length will cause reflections and cause over-voltage/latchup.

The rise times need to be >50 ns to keep the electrical length to 1/10th the wavelength or less:

$$\lambda/10 = 1.25 m => t_{rise} > 42 ns. 
$$

My plan is to add a 10 Ohm/ 1nF: $$\tau=68 ns$$ low pass filter to limit the rise time.

Any other ideas?

The stuff inside the dashed line is located 1.25 meters away on a cable.
[image]

Comment: I looks like you are using Schmidt Trigger inverters. There is no need for these to be  ST's. What's your reason for using them?

Comment: Low voltage switching can only produce high voltages if there is high inductance or high currents involved and your line will not have enough inductance so will be fine. You can also make a simple voltage reverser with a DPDT relay if that is more convenient. Also a better way to slow the rise time on the leds would be to place a capacitor across the wires at the beginning of the length of wire but then it would need to be bipolar.

Comment: @FiddyOhm you are right that Schmitt trigger is probably not needed. In general for mixed-domain stuff I prefer Schmitt triggers. Keep in mind this is not cost-optimized and reuse is preferred.

Comment: @TWiz : A HS logic gate can cause <10ns transitions when driving a 50 pF capacitive load. If the electrical load is not matched to the cable reflections can definitely cause over-voltages on the driver.

Comment: Is using an actual H-bridge not an option? Something that could drive the required current with slower edges sounds like a good solution.

Comment: Looks okay. Have you excluded trapezoidal drivers (not the high speed ones, but ones often used for h-bridge drivers like the IRS2608D that exhibit long enough guarantees?) That's perhaps too boutique for me and I prefer your approach. But you might have a different opinion.

Comment: With such a low current the induced emf on such a wire should still be fine but if going much longer you would want to have a capacitor between the outputs of the inverters, the resistors should not be necessary. You may find you can use less components with 3 wires especially if the input to the inverters is the same voltage as their output so you can just use a single inverter and still give both leds the same current.

Comment: @mcintoda The output of a 74xx series schimdt trigger is the same as any other 74xx gate or device. The inputs are what is special about the Schmidt triggers in these devices. It is the outputs which are driving the long wires in your application. Their inputs are all connected to logic signals here. Don't forget to connect the  other inputs in the package to Gnd or Vcc if you are not using them (maybe just not shown in your schematic?).